# Add product as a custom option

Tags: custom-options, multiple

I want to show another product that can be added to cart  when you tick the check box near it.It must be something like a combo product.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somehow vague, but If I understood what you mean, then I think you need bundle products.
Or, if you want your second product to be a separate product and to be added separately to the cart, try adding it as a related product.
Magento allows you to add related products to the cart along with the main product.

Comment: It is not exeactly bundled product or related product actually I want to show  product in custom options .So that if the user ticks mark that product it will be added to cart simultanously.

Comment: You cannot do that. You cannot have a product as a custom option. But you can move the related products block in the custom options zone for the same visual effect.